# Matrix alignment …. can we capture it

Tags: matrices

Given two vectors $\mathbf{m1},\mathbf{m2}$ in $n$-$dimensional$ space, we can check whether they are positively aligned of negatively aligned by using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

$\mathbf{m1}.\mathbf{m2}=\|\mathbf{m1}\|\|\mathbf{m2}\|\cos(\theta)$

I was wondering if we have a similar notion of alignment in case of $matrices $ as well. If yes then how do we capture it?

For-example, can we say that $M1,M2 \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ are positively aligned?
I couldn't think of useful tags for my question and any useful edit will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with alignment in the vector case?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

In a certain sense, two matrices $A,B$ are "aligned" if the signs of their eigenvalues $(-1,0,1)$ have the same multiplicities. Then you can show that you can transform one matrix into the other through "positive" transformations.

For symmetric matrices, see for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixSignature.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate this idea. Or can give a reference where I can find more detail.

Comment: I added an easy reference for symmetric matrices. It would be harder to explain in detail what I mean for two general matrices.

Comment: Thank you for giving reference.